# Map separable points to a dimension 1 space

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am given a dataset of points in $R^2$. You can see a representation of these points on the following image : [image]

I want to find a function $f:R^2 \to R$, such that all the points in my dataset are linearly separable. So what I want is to represent my blue and yellow points in a space of dimension 1, with a clear separation between points of different color.

---

I decided to use the function $f$ that for a point $X = (x_1,x_2)$ returns the product of its coordinates, so $f(X) = x_1\times x_2$. Since the coordinates of the yellow points have the same sign, and since the coordinates of the blue points have opposite signs the points can be linearly separable. But by doing this some of the points like $x = (-1,1)$ and $y = (1,-1)$ may overlap each other. So I was wondering if there exists a function that could make my points linearly separable without the overlaping of points ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine the data points as lying on a sheet of paper.Two successive folds, whose crease lines have slope $\pm 1$ through the origin, will fold the sheet into a right-angled wedge, and the two colors will lie on opposite halves of that wedge. Thus at the end of these two transformations the colored dots are linearly separable.
P.S. The folding operations can be accomplished using absolute value functions. All this is simpler if you first rotate the data set by 45 degrees.